# How to write short logical expressions in Java?

Tags: java, logical-operators

Is there a way to make consecutive logical operations on the same variable shorter?

*Example:*

```
if (animation.getStatus() == Animation.Status.PAUSED || animation.getStatus() == Animation.Status.STOPPED) {
    animation.playFromStart();
} else if (animation.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
    animation.stop();
}
```

You see in the if-clause that there I check the `animation.getStatus()` twice, once for paused and once for stopped.
Is there a way to make it like `animation.getStatus() == Animation.Status.PAUSED || Animation.Status.STOPPED`?

I'm sure this question has been asked already but I really don't know what to search for, so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Not really, no.  The best you could do is refactor that to a variable if the call is particularly expensive.

Comment: If Animation.Status is enum, then this could be helpfull:

EnumSet<> notRunning = EnumSet.of(Animation.Status.PAUSED, Animation.Status.STOPPED);

then you do if (notRunning.contains(animation.getStatus())

To make it better, your enum (Animation.Status) could have static method return that EnumSet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; Java syntax is immutable.

There are several options, but the easiest is to refactor, which as a bonus makes it legible, e.g.,

```
if (animation.shouldReplay()) {
    animation.playFromStart();
} else if (animation.shouldStop() {
    animation.stop();
}
```

Or a level deeper, e.g.,

```
animation.controlFromCurrentStatus();
```

If you're unwilling to encapsulate, simply importing the statuses helps:

```
Animation.Status currentStatus = animation.getStatus();
if (currentStatus == PAUSED || currentStatus == STOPPED) {
    animation.playFromStart();
} else if (currentStatus == RUNNING) {
    animation.stop();
}
```

Or make them `enum`s, which arguably they should be anyway:

```
switch (currentStatus) {
case PAUSED:
case STOPPED:
    animation.playFromStart();
    break;
case RUNNING:
    animation.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case `switch` statement would look nice

```
switch (animation.getStatus()) {
    case Animation.Status.PAUSED:
    case Animation.Status.STOPPED:
        animation.playFromStart();
        break;
    case Animation.Status.RUNNING:
        animation.stop();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a couple of ways:

1. **By introducing a temporary variable** - make a variable, assign the status to it, and use the value of the variable in the expressions instead of making the call multiple times
2. **By writing a helper method** - write a method that takes the current status and a variable argument list of statuses, and call this method in the conditional.

Here is the illustration to the first way of doing it:

```
Animation.Status status = animation.getStatus();
if (status == Animation.Status.PAUSED || status == Animation.Status.STOPPED) {
    animation.playFromStart();
} else if (status == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
    animation.stop();
}
```

Here is an illustration to the second way of doing it:

```
private static boolean checkStatus(Animation.Status status, Animation.Status... expected) {
    for (Animation.Status e : expected) {
        if (e == status) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
...
if (checkStatus(animation.getStatus(), Animation.Status.PAUSED, Animation.Status.STOPPED)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is multithreaded, which it probably should be if you're running animations and want to be able to stop/start/pause them, then you should consider synchronization.

So to take Dave Newtons code snippet and make it thread-safe:

```
synchronized(this){
    if (animation.shouldReplay()) {
        animation.playFromStart();
    } else if (animation.shouldStop() {
       animation.stop();
    }
}
```

Thus, there is no danger the first condition will return false, then the current thread is no longer Running, another thread modifies the status of the animation, then the current thread again becomes Runnable and tries to stop the animation.